# How to unchecked radio button using radio group

Tags: android

how to multiple radio button unchecked using radio group please mention
I know that this question is already exist on this site but code is not working app is crashed using this (
radiogroup.clear) 
please send correct code

Comment: add the crash log

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
Radiobutton radiobutton=null;

radiobutton=yourradiogroup.getcheckedid;
if(radiobutton.ischecked)
{
radiobutton.setchecked(false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, selecting another `RadioButton` will clear the previous selection.

```
<RadioGroup
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:checkedButton="@+id/checkedInitialbtn"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:text="Option1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/checkedInitialbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
<RadioButton
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/china_and_india"
  android:textSize="18sp"
  android:checked="false"
  android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
  android:background="@color/black"
  android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
  />
```